# svg export to png only exports small part/fraction of rendered svg in JavaScript using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I need some advice on exporting a rendered svg word cloud to png.

I got my setup to work sort-of, but it only exports a fraction of the rendered word cloud.

I think it might be related to sizes I need to set. I am not sure.

**This is my Angular/JavaScript export function:**

```
scope.exportToPNG2 = function () {

  var svg = document.querySelector('#wordCloudSVG');

  var canvas = document.getElementById('WordCloudCanvas');

  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var data = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
  var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

  var img = new Image();
  var svgBlob = new Blob([data], { type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8' });
  var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

  img.onload = function () {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

      var imgURI = canvas
          .toDataURL('image/png')
          .replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');

      triggerDownload(imgURI);
  };

  img.src = url;
}


function triggerDownload(imgURI) {
  var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
      view: window,
      bubbles: false,
      cancelable: true
  });

  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.setAttribute('download', 'MY_COOL_IMAGE.png');
  a.setAttribute('href', imgURI);
  a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

  a.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

**This is the template where my word cloud is rendered to:**

```
<div id="wordCloud">
    <button class="basicButton" ng-click="exportToPNG2()">Export to .PNG</button>
    <div id="wordCloudVisualisation"></div>
    <canvas id="WordCloudCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

**This image shows my `<div>` where my word cloud is rendered to. The Yellow highlighted block, is the portion of the word cloud that gets re-drawn as a png and exported:**

[image]

**The element id in `var svg = document.querySelector('#wordCloudSVG');` I got from this in my Chrome dev tools:**

[image]

**What must I change to export the entire word cloud?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made some minor changes to my export function thanks to this post: https://gist.github.com/gustavohenke/9073132

I am setting the canvas size based on the `svg.getBoundingClientRect()`

**Here is my working solution (see comments in code):**

```
scope.exportToPNG2 = function () {

  var svg = document.querySelector('#wordCloudSVG');

  //create a canvas
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

  //set size for the canvas
  var svgSize = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
  canvas.width = svgSize.width;
  canvas.height = svgSize.height;

  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var data = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);

  var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

  var img = new Image();
  var svgBlob = new Blob([data], { type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8' });
  var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

  img.onload = function () {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

      var imgURI = canvas
          .toDataURL('image/png')
          .replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');

      triggerDownload(imgURI);
  };

  img.src = url;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your canvas `width` and `height` properties to the `natural..` ones of your svg image.

```
img.onload = function () {
    canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
    canvas.heigh = this.naturalHeight;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);
    ...
```

However note that IE doesn't set `img`'s width/height when they point to svg docs, so you'd have to parse it from the document's element. Since here you are setting your svg's `width`and `height` attributes to the default px, you could get it easily.
(But note that you'll run into more problems with IE with this method anyway...)

Comment: Thank you for the response! I was able to fix it, setting the width and height of my canvas based on the sizes of my svg.

Comment: @onmyway , Yes I see this. Glad you sorted it out by yourself. But note that what you are doing is not exactly the same, since you could have some CSS rules on your svg element which would make `getBoundingClientRect` return other values (basically you'll get the displayed size with your method). Since we are talking a bout vector graphics, both are acceptable, but you have to know the difference to know which one you want.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :). Noted.